# Play music by Operator in asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

I want in call duration between operator and caller,play sound for operator(something like hold music).
**`But in order to play this sound, operator must dial unique code and then sound will be play for caller, and caller only hear that sound file!`**
After that (sound fully played), caller back to operator's queue or something like this.

So is this possible to do or not? (if possible, post dial-plan for this too)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question, you want the operator to be able to make a caller hear a sound for a set period of time before returning to the operator?

If so, the FreePBX interface for Asterisk has a 'parking lot' feature that can be programmed to park a call (caller hears hold music) for a set period of time and if the call is not manually unparked you can make it automatically return to the operator (or elsewhere). This may do what you want.

http://www.freepbx.org/support/documentation/module-documentation/parking-lot

You may also be able to program this feature manually or through your Asterisk admin front end of choice but I have only set it up through FreePBX.